# failure to launch exe from ant

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am using Jenkins to run an Ant script which in turn launches an exe. The exe fails to launch. I get no results at all. The exe opens fine on the server without Jenkins via Ant. Other exe files do seem to launch OK. The only thing I can see that is different is that my problematic exe opens a dialog which then automatically closes. Does anyone have an idea how to get Jenkins to launch my exe? Is there some setting or parameter I am missing?

I am calling the exe with the exec task and passing in arguments.

If I try to run the exe directly from Jenkins using "Execute Windows Batch Command" I also get no results.

Comment: Please format question.

Comment: Post your ant file - or at least the task that does the exec.  output of running with --verbose would also help.  When you say it works on the server did you run it as the same user?  likely something is different in your environment

Comment: Jenkins is running under the server's name, while when I run from the command line env.USERNAME provides my login information. I see a difference that when I log into the server env.HOMEPATH is set to env.HOMEPATH = \Users\administrator while when running from Jenkins that is null

Comment: I set the Jenkins service to run as Administrator so the environment variables match the results I get when running from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

once I set the Jenkins service to run under a real login instead of just using the system account, the application runs.